# Does clearing phone cache clears Firestore persistence?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

If on Android, user presses clear cache (not clear data) or use any cleaner app (like clean master etc), will the Firestore persistence data be cleared?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If on android, user presses clear cache (not clear data) or use any cleaner app (like clean master etc), will the firestore persistence data be cleared?

Yes, it will. According to the official documentation regarding [Firestore offline persistence](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline):

> Cloud Firestore supports offline data persistence. This feature caches a copy of the Cloud Firestore data that your app is actively using, so your app can access the data when the device is offline.

So this means that the client will persist active and recent data to disk. If you clear the cache, you need to get the data again. This technique is not quite recommender in case on Firestore since getting all the data again will cost you a read operation for every document you read.

Comment: Now it makes sense. Sorry couldn't upvote because I'm new here. But thank you so much. :)